# How to load photoshop action with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, action

How do I load  photoshop's action using its javascript scripting language?
Mostly curious in this action steps:
Add Noise
            Distribution: gaussian
            Percent: 2%
            With Monochromatic
Texturizer
            Texture Type: Canvas
            Scaling: 100
            Relief: 3
            Without Invert Texture
            Light Direction: Top Left

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish to apply two effects.
1)**Noise Distribution**

2)**Texturizer**


You should first select designated layer,before applying any effects.
You can achieve that by selecting by its name

```
layerRef = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("Layer 1");
```

Then,you can apply the effect #1,by **applyAddNoise** method.This method requires thress parameters as follows: 
**amount** (percentage)
**NoiseDistribution** (GAUSSIAN or UNIFORM)
**Monochromatic** (boolean -> true or false)

```
layerRef.applyAddNoise(2.0,NoiseDistribution.GAUSSIAN,true);
```

Unfortunately,I could not find any method or documentation that makes texturizer effect at present.

Hope this helps
Myra